# For my C assignment, I am don't understand what it means by using redirection to test the program?

Tags: c

I don't understand what my assignment means about redirection. My assignment says:

> Use input redirection to test your program. Note that your program
>   reads from the user using scanf and input redirection feeds the file
>   contents to your program. You don’t have to use any file operations in
>   your program. Consider the following file a.txt:
>
> ```
> 4 
> 10 
> 20 
> 15 
> 5 
> -1
> ```

Does this mean that I have to make a a.text file? where does the a.txt file with the numbers even come from???

Comment: It's saying you create the text file using a text editor just once and save it.  When running your program you then redirect it to the executable as a replacement for the keyboard input.

Comment: what is the scanf for then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructor is telling you to create a text file with a series of numbers in it to feed to your program.  Input redirection means using `<` at the shell when running your program to make it use the given file as stdin.

For example:

```
./myprogram < a.txt
```

The file `a.txt` is treated as the program's stdin.

Comment: but then what is the scanf is for?

Comment: @Su.she `scanf` reads from stdin.  Without the redirect, stdin is the terminal i.e. you type the numbers manually.  With the redirect you aren't prompted and the file acts as stdin.

Comment: so I am supposed have a scanf statement?

Comment: @Su.she If that's what the assignment says, then yes, just like your other programs.

Comment: @Su.she Also, if someone answers your question and it fixes your problem, you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).  You've got quite a few questions out and none of them have an accepted answer.  People might not want to answer your questions if you keep doing that.

Comment: Ohh sorry I didn't know about the accept thing. I only upvoted.

Comment: @Su.she Thanks.  You may want to review your others questions for the same.

Comment: ok so my steps are: 1.write the code for the assignment 2.Code will have a scanf to scan user inputs  3. redirect a.txt to test program.  how is the file and user input connected?

Comment: @Su.she As mentioned in this answer.  Use redirection to make the program treat the file as if it was interactive input.

Comment: omg I feel so dumb. What is a.txt file will have then?? it has to have something in it right???

Comment: It will have exactly the values you mentioned in the question.

Comment: so the file will have 4 10 20 15 5 -1. Redirecting will test the code with those values. Is a.txt file only for testing and nothing else? my actual output will depend on what the user entered???

Comment: @Su.she That's what the assignment says: the redirected file is for testing.  The program will behave the same way when a user enters the data, and the output depends on the input, like it does for any program.